# Disease on Morning Glories

Tags: diagnosis, morning-glory

[image]

Can you tell me what has killed my beautiful morning glories this year? I am just sick as they covered the whole side of my house. How do I keep this from happening again?

Answer (score 0):

Take a leaf to a gardening center right away for identification of the problem. It might be some kind of mold or mildew.

Answer (score 0):

Fungal disease of some sort, look under different leaves, see if there are orange rust spots. (to see if the plant has rust). but what to do? keep leaves dry, make sure irrigation spray stays off them. Sorry I dont know what treatment.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect bacterial leaf scorch. Do you see it only on this plant? Does it spread elsewhere?

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xylella_fastidiosa

I would still suggest taking a leaf sample (or a detailed photo) to  a nursery for second opinion.